# Ninja privilege escalation problem

Tags: security, root

I have a problem with ninja. I think I have configured it correctly. However, when I type in `su test` to login as test and then run `sudo -i` the log shows that test is in the ninja group when in reality it is not. Also, it does not show up as an unauthorized process. What might I be doing wrong to not trigger an unauthorized process alert to the log? The ninja page is [here](http://forkbomb.org/ninja/). The guide I used is [here](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-ninja/). The log I got is:

`[Sun Jun  9 08:08:41 2013] NEW ROOT PROCESS: sudo[6332] ppid=6244 uid=0 gid=1001
[Sun Jun  9 08:08:41 2013]   - ppid uid=1001(test) gid=1001 ppid=6232
[Sun Jun  9 08:08:41 2013]   + test is in magic group, all OK!`

Test is not in the "magic" group.

Comment: http://forkbomb.org/ninja/

Comment: Can you confirm in the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files that test isn't in the magic group?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that test isn't in the magic group. However, root, messagebus, and gabe are in the magic group.

Comment: Double check your setup with his updated tutorial: http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-ninja-ubuntu-10-04/

Comment: i followed the instructions in the tutorial and ninja still thinks every single user is in the "magic" group and I can't get it to only allow the users in the group

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `su - test` instead. You're not completely sourcing the test user's environment when you use the command `su test`.

Comment: i tried... it still says test is in the "magic" group. :(

Comment: Why / how should that influence the group membership? This influences the shell initialization only. Account handling is not done by the shell (though it probably could drop group memberships).